# SSAS : Using drill through action to collapse by an MDX condition

Tags: ssas, mdx, bids

I have a ragged user hierarchy,with a custom internal hierarchy within the dimension, called [Dim User].[User Hierarchy] which is based on a denormalised Level1, Level2, Level3, Level4, Level5. What I want is that the user hierarchy is collapsed based on a condition that the user type of a descendant of user type SHOP.

What I have done is created a drill through action, with this condition :

```
IIF([Dim User Balance].[User Type Key].CurrentMember IS 
descendants({[Dim User Type].[UserTypeIdHierarchy].&[9]},0,self), TRUE, FALSE)
```

However when I try to access the drill through action, I cannot seem to find it anywhere? What am I missing? Or maybe is there anyway better to do this?

When trying to do this with mdx, this query is leaving out members :

```
SELECT
{  
[Measures].[Measure] 
    } ON 0, non empty  { 
        FILTER (
            {[Dim User].[User Hierarchy].[Level1].allmembers  }
            ,[Dim User].[User Hierarchy].CurrentMember.Children.Count > 1
        ) 
    } ON 1

    from [cube]
```

And when doing it like this:

```
SELECT
{  
[Measures].[comp money in] 
    } ON columns,{
    descendants( [Dim User].[UserHierarchy].children,0,self) * 
    descendants([Dim User].[UserTypeIdHierarchy].&[9],0,self)}
    on rows
    from [activities]
```

It is excluding the descendants of the user hierarchy in the measures, which is not what I want. I want all figures still to be aggregated. It is what I display on my Y axis that I am concerned of. I want it focused on specific user types, which are descending from 9.

Comment: How are you trying to access the drill through action? Which client tool are you using?

Comment: First off I would like to access it with the cube browser, in BIDS - however I cannot access it from there, or not even in excel 2010. For the moment I would like to see if the drill through action is actually working as it should.

Comment: Does this: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/perform-an-olap-server-action-in-a-pivottable-report-HA010177379.aspx help you to access the action from Excel?

Comment: I already tried the power pivot. No I cannot access it from there.

Comment: The mentioned article does not talk about PowerPivot, but pivot tables in Excel based on Analysis Services **cubes**.

Comment: Hi @FrankPl I was meant to say I tried both excel and power pivot in excel, and I cannot access my action from either of them.

Comment: @StephenBorgTo be clear, you created a pivot table connected to your SSAS cube in Excel, right clicked on a value in the pivot table and your drill through action was not available under Additional Actions?

Comment: @mmarie yes that is correct.

Comment: Hi @FrankPl,see my edited question.